# Create sequence by choosing middle elements

Tags: java, arrays

I am fresher programmer and stuck at below point,

I want a method that take in input an array, let say,

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o]
```

and return below sequence in output,
(i.e. find middle and add to array)

```
[h, d, l, b, j, f, n, c, i, e, k, g, m, a, o]
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I tried couple of recursive functions but unable to get what I want

Comment: @SpectraTesting yes, I think you could do that with a recursive function

Comment: @Spectra Testing - it's more that there is a deeply ingrained cultural bias against helping people with obvious homework questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an iterative deepening method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] input = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k",
        "l", "m", "n", "o"};
    String[] output = resequence(input);
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(output));
}

private static String[] resequence(String[] input) {
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int depth = 0; output.size() != input.length; ++depth) {
        iteration(input, 0, input.length, depth, 0, output);
    }
    return output.toArray(new String[output.size()]);
}

private static void iteration(String[] input, int min, int max,
        int target, int depth, List<String> output) {
    if (min < max) {
        int middle = (min+max)/2;
        if (target == depth) {
            output.add(input[middle]);
        } else {
            iteration(input, min, middle, target, depth+1, output);
            iteration(input, middle+1, max, target, depth+1, output);
        }
    }
}
```

But the output of this is:

```
[h, d, l, b, f, j, n, a, c, e, g, i, k, m, o]
```

UPDATE

With a breadth first method:

```
static class Interval {
    private final int min;
    private final int max;

    Interval(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }
}

private static String[] resequence(String[] input) {
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    if (input.length > 0) {
        List<Interval> queue = new ArrayList<>();
        queue.add(new Interval(0, input.length));
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Interval ival = queue.remove(0);
            int middle = (ival.min+ival.max)/2;
            output.add(input[middle]);
            if (middle > ival.min) {
                queue.add(new Interval(ival.min, middle));
            }
            if (middle+1 < ival.max) {
                queue.add(new Interval(middle+1, ival.max));
            }
        }
    }
    return output.toArray(new String[output.size()]);
}
```

The output is:

```
[h, d, l, b, f, j, n, a, c, e, g, i, k, m, o]
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, it's helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

suppose the i/p array is `array1` which contains `{a,b,c......m,n,o}`. if you want your output array storing middle elements, create another array `array2` and store the middle elements of `array1` into `array2` and then remove the middle element from `array1` and continue the above process till the `array1` becomes empty.

you can remove the elements from `array1` by following any of the process

```
array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, element) //element is middle element of `array1` in your case
```

or you can do it by using `for` loop as

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
// Delete Function
if (pos == i) { //pos is nothing but middle element
for (int j = i + 1; i < array1.length - 1; j++) {
array1[i] = array[j];
i++;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Oh, he's making a binary tree, I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

So what you're trying to do is play the 'think of a number between 1 and 100' game.  In computer science we call this a Divide and Conquer algorithm.  Of all the things in an undergrad compsci degree it's one of the most important and useful.

So how this game works:

First you pick 50.  Then if the target number is higher than 50 you pick 75.  Then if it's less than 75 you pick 62 (or 63).

It's a binary search - because at each point you have two options (well, four really - higher/lower/we found it/it's not in the tree).

So we can find the target number out of 100 in about 7 guesses (natural log(100)), which for large values of N is a **huge** speed improvement.

So what you're really trying to do is take this:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o]
```

and turn it into this:

```
[                     h                     ]
[         d,                      l,        ]
[   b           f           j,          n,  ]
[a,    c,    e,    g,    i,    k,    m,    o]
```

And then you're stepping down the tree from the 'root'(which is at the top of the diagram)

To do this recursively - use a pseudo algorithm like so:

```
 array pseudoRearrangeArray(arrayToRearrange) {
      return new array made up of:
          middle number
          +
          pseudoRearrangeArray(everything to the left of middle number)
          +
          pseudoRearrangeArray(everything to the right of middle number)
  }
```

Except of course that's wrong, because it'll output [ h, d, b, a, c, ...

See if you can figure out why, and how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, actually it;s returning pre-order sequence, wheres I want sequences like balanced BST :)